# Confusion about John Lee's definition of Riemannian distance

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves

I am new in differential/Riemannian geometry and I am working right now with the book of John Lee, *Introduction of Riemannian Manifolds*. He defines the distance of $p$ and $q$ ($p,q\in M$, $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold) as the infimum of the length of all *admissible* curves, i.e. piecewise regular, such that the endpoints of the curve are $p$ and $q$. He also consider maps of the form
$$c\colon \{t_o\} \to M$$
as admissible curve. (Let us say that $c(t_0)=p$.) The length of a curve $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to M$ is defined as
$$L_g(\gamma):=\int_a^b |\gamma '(t)|_g\, dt.$$
What confuses me is that $c '(t_0)$ is not defined. How is the length of $c$ defined? I know that the answer should be zero, since the distance from $p$ to $p$ should be zero (if not, then it wouldn't be a distance to begin with). But is it because
$$\int_a^a f(t)\, dt=0$$
for all measurable functions $f$? Or would it be better to *define* the length of such "point"-curves to be zero?

I know that other books, such *Riemannian Geometry* from Manfredo P. do Carmo, just define length and distance on piecewise smooth curves. There we can define a curve from $p$ to $p$ as $\gamma(t)=p$ for all $t\in I$ and any interval $I$. Then it is easy to see that $\gamma '(t)=0$ and the length is zero, since the integral over the zero function is zero. But I cannot adopt it to the definition above, since $\gamma$ would not be admissible anymore.

Comment: Either you extend the derivative by letting $c'(t_0)=0$ or you extend the length by letting $L_g(c):=0$, but I agree with you that in all cases you expect the resulting length to be $0$ and thus have to make such choices.

Comment: Do you thing there is a way to avoid defining something extra, if we use admissible curves like in Lee's book?

Comment: I tried to read the part where he describes admissible curves, and I think that if by "compact interval" you take sets of the form $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ you are precisely in do Carmo's setting. But perhaps I missed the part where he introduces and discusses constant curves, and also you are not so happy to do that since $[a,a]=\{x\,;\,a\leq x\leq a\}=\{a\}$ makes perfectly sense.

Comment: The biggest confusion I had was with the restriction that smooth curves should have non-zero derivatives (or finite many zero derivatives). Since in the definition of do Carmo (p.42-43) he just defined it on compact interval of a smooth curve. He even wrote that it can have "corners" etc. which doesn't happen in Lee's definition. "Do Carmo's curve" can have infinite many points where the derivative is zero (countable and non-countable), where "Lee's curve" only finite many. So how can it be in the same setting then?

Also, thanks for your time and sorry for that many questions!

Comment: A curve also can have corners with Lee's def: $[-1,0]\ni t\mapsto(t,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $[0,1]\ni t\mapsto (0,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ defines a piecewise smooth curve $[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ segment in his setting. Also I don't see anywhere where he requires the derivatives of the curves to have finitely many zeroes: perhaps we are not reading the same edition (I am reading the second one)?

Comment: And, if it is what you were thinking about, allowing only the cases where there is a finite number of points $t_i$ s.t. $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ is smooth allows you to define the integral $\int|\gamma'(t)|_gdt$ as a finite sum, while in do Carmo you perhaps have to discuss limits (I can't find the book at the library, and I read Lee's book a lot more than do Carmo's, so perhaps I will let someone who better studied it answer you!)